# Trying to sum columns in Pandas dataframe, issue with index it seems

Tags: pandas, sum, multiple-columns

Trying to sum columns in Pandas dataframe, issue with index it seems...

Part of dataset looks like this, for multiple years:
[snapshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G01ZN.png)

CA_HousingTrend = CA_HousingTrend_temp.pivot_table(index='YEAR',columns='UNITSSTR', aggfunc='size')

[dataframe looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz8eH.png) and
[this is the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXwvz.png)

Trying to sum multi-family units so I am specifying the columns to sum
cols = ['05', '06']

CA_HousingTrend['sum_stats'] = CA_HousingTrend[cols].sum(axis=1)

This is the error I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 5, in 
File "/Users/alexandramaxim/Documents/Py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3511, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G01ZN.png)
File "/Users/alexandramaxim/Documents/Py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
File "/Users/alexandramaxim/Documents/Py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['05', '06'], dtype='object', name='UNITSSTR')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the index, but the pivot probably created a multi-index. Try this.

```
CA_HousingTrend = CA_HousingTrend_temp.pivot_table(index='YEAR',columns='UNITSSTR', aggfunc='size')
# A new dataframe just so you have something new to play with.
new_df = CA_Housing_Trend_temp.reset_index()
```